# How to fix duplicate taggings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

Users can submit tags for Habits, Goals, Values, and Stats.

When a user clicks on a tag in the `tag_cloud` he is redirected to the home page with all the instances of that tag, but for some reason the instances that fall under Habits are duplicating.

[image]

Any ideas on why this is?

**pages_controller**

```
@habits = current_user.habits.tagged_with(params[:tag])
```

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
  before_save :set_tag_owner

  def set_tag_owner 
    # Set the owner of some tags based on the current tag_list
    set_owner_tag_list_on(self.user, :tags, self.tag_list)
    # Clear the list so we don't get duplicate taggings (hmmm what does this mean? I copied this code & comment from somewhere else)
    # self.tag_list = nil
  end
```

In **views/home.html.erb**: `<%= render @habits %>` in **routes.rb**: `root 'pages#home'`.

I tried to post only the relevant stuff, but here's the **[gist](http://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried uncommenting th line:

```
self.tag_list = nil
```

I guess you copied it over from [this source](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/111) or the linked stackoverflow question ? 
In your code comments you asked what the following comment line is about:

> Clear the list so we don't get duplicate taggings

I digged through the [sources](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/5fc745165a3eb6ddbd0505d75c80e8fb7b1afd09/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/ownership.rb#L61) and found the method you are calling:

```
def set_owner_tag_list_on(owner, context, new_list)
```

So as the last parameter is called new_list, i guess the old list, that you hand in to the `set_owner_tag_list_on` method, is would set the same tags again. Therefore the old `tag_list` without the owner is set to nil there, as `tag_list` only seems to contain the tags without owner (according to the [docs](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-ownership))

Although I don't really see the point of using this owned taggings after all, since you create new habits for every user and always filter by user. As far as I can tell the ownership feature of acts_as_taggable_on is only useful when you have one recource that is tagged by multiple users and you want to know who tagged what. In your case everyone has his own taggable resources.