# How to make a model callback conditional based upon controller actions [:create, :update]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I wanted to do something like this in **goal.rb**

```
  before_save :set_tag_owner,:if => [:create, :update]

  def set_tag_owner
    # Set the owner of some tags based on the current tag_list
    set_owner_tag_list_on(self.user, :tags, self.tag_list)
    self.tag_list = nil
  end
```

I want this method to work before save for only the create and update actions of the **goals_controller**.

Otherwise I run into the problem with the tagging that when a goal is marked as accomplished the tag then disappears because `set_tag_owner` is setting its tags to `nil`.

```
  def mark_accomplished
    @goal.update(accomplished: true)
  end

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    @goal.save
    respond_modal_with @goal, location: root_path, notice: 'Goal was successfully created! Go chase those dreams!'
  end

  def update
    @goal.update(goal_params)
    respond_modal_with @goal, location: root_path
  end
```

I need this line though `self.tag_list = nil` because without it a tag is double rendered

I also tried applying that goal model logic inside the controller via a `before_action` callback, but I was getting an `undefined` error even if I changed `self` to `@goal`.

Comment: Why not simply call set_tag_owner in the create and update methods in your controller?

Comment: If you only want to execute `set_tag_owner` on the create or update of the record, for which action(s) should it not be called? because I can't see why you need this...

Comment: @MrYoshiji it shouldn't be called on `mark_accomplished`. Right now if a user clicks the button that triggers `mark_accomplished` the tag associated with that goal disappears. I don't have this problem with the update action because when a user updates a goal the form is repopulated with the tag.

Comment: You might want to fix the problem at the source instead of trying to avoid it when it occurs... But I can understand that it is not easy to get rid of this issue of double-rendering... I saw your other post yesterday and couldn't find a solution for you :/

Comment: I tried to do that @bumpy. Maybe I did it wrong. Can you show me how that'd look? For example I put `set_owner_tag_list_on(@goal.user, :tags, @goal.tag_list) @goal.tag_list = nil` in create and I get the error: `undefined method 'set_owner_tag_list_on'`

Comment: Maybe this sheds light @MrYoshiji http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643598/how-to-fix-duplicate-taggings. I had implemented his suggestions not fully understanding what he meant and still not understanding.

Comment: the third argument of `set_owner_tag_list_on` should be the list of the new tags, not the old ones. also the last comment on this thread might help https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/111

Comment: @MrYoshiji that gives: `undefined local variable or method `new_list'` if I switch out `tag_list`

Comment: And @MrYoshiji I don't get the purpose of `User.find(:first).tag( @goal, :with => params[:goal].delete(:tag_list), :on => :tags )`. Am I suppose to put this in the `set_tag_owner` method because if so that gives `Couldn't find User with 'id'=first`

Comment: You think that last line should be in place of `self.tag_list = nil`?

Comment: no no, i don't know your app and I can't really help but it seems that you are not confortable with Rails. Maybe you should stick with a workaround... Your `before_action` workaround does not work on `@goal` is not set yet

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji I'll keep plowing away trying to figure out a workaround then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to add an attr_accessor to your model and use that to stop the before_save

An example

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :dont_set_tag_owner

  before_save :set_tag_owner, :unless => dont_set_tag_owner

  def set_tag_owner
    # Set the owner of some tags based on the current tag_list
    set_owner_tag_list_on(self.user, :tags, self.tag_list)
    self.tag_list = nil
  end

end
```

Then, in the controller

```
def mark_accomplished
  @goal.update(accomplished: true, :dont_set_tag_owner => true)
end
```

And, just to give you one more option - depending on your needs for updated_at, you can also do this

```
def mark_accomplished
  @goal.update_column(accomplished: true)
end
```